# Custom Pipe failing conditionals that work fine in a method

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a custom pipe that returns a string based on a few conditions but for some reason it is always returning the first even if the conditional is not met in the component.

I have made a method with the identical if/else statements and it works find there

```
  transform(orderType: String, completed: Boolean, requestType: String): any{
    if (completed && orderType !== 'web') {
      console.log('1');
      return 'not web';
    } else if (completed && orderType === 'web')  {
      console.log('2');
      return 'web';
    } else {
      return 'N/A';
    }
  }
```

Below is where I am calling it:

```
     {{ this.orderType| getOrderType: this.order.requestType: this.completed}} {{this.order.requestType}}
```

I have the requestType and completed console.logging in the console and it is logging what it should be.

So it is passing if even though it is equal to web and returning not web

Comment: You have the order of the pipe parameters wrong in the template.

Comment: Oh well that is embarrassing. Running on a lack of sleep and stuff really does mess you up. Thank you for the quick and correct answer.

Comment: It happens. You can use an object next time with properties instead of having many parameters for a pipe. As it gets different to manage, especially if a parameter needs to be optional

Answer (score 0):

The order of parameter or wrong,pass the completed before requestType as you are capturing in this order in class

```
{{ this.orderType| getOrderType: this.completed:this.order.requestType}} {{this.order.requestType}}
```